# Datatables with selectable rows and a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

1) in my current project i use a datatable with selectable rows (click to highlight/select a row).

2) each row contains a bootstrap dropdown inside the last column.

The Problem:

When i click the row, the row gets selected, thats fine. But wenn i click the dropdown, the row gets selected, too. i dont want that. how can i achieve this?! Is there any way to prevent the row from being selected when i click the dropdown in the last column?

My dropdown code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Aktion <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">OptionA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OptionB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OptionC</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My datatable code:

```
$('#invoiceList').dataTable({
    "displayLength": -1,
    "paginate": true,
    "order": [[3, "desc"]],
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "Alle"]],
    "ajax": "get_invoices.php",
    "deferRender": true
});

$('#invoiceList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. by using event-delegation i get notified for the click event of the ajax-loaded dropdown. then i can just remove the active class from all rows in the table.

```
$(document).on("click", '.dropdown-toggle', function(event) { 
            console.log('clicked dropdown');
            $('#invoiceList tbody tr').removeClass('active');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you can try, something like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault(); //or e.stopPropagation(); which should work better
});
```

Comment: thanks, already thought of something like this, but both (preventDefault & stopPropagation) do not stop the row of being selected :/